# Global meta discussion of simple ways to automatically generate standard, smaller, image sizes

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A proposal has [recently been made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107927/164163) on global meta regarding automatic resizing of images to a standard (generally smaller) size to improve layout and avoid the overhead and inconvenience of [huge images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101439/164163).

It [turns out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-pho/101446#101446) that *imgur.com* generates scaled down images automatically, and that support of such a feature would (at least apparently) be a straightforward matter of [minor adjustments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107927/embed-smaller-version-of-images-from-imgur-com-to-reduce-traffic/107991#107991) to the `![description][X]` code.

If you have a view on the subject, please join that discussion.

Comment: As long as the non-problematicly sized images are not touch, I don't mind. But every image I've uploaded will not resist rescaling without losing quality...